# Bitnami Jenkins VM: Why the pipeline is missing permissions while trying to checkout a git repo when running second time?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

this is my first question here, so please keep in mind. =)

I am using the Bitnami Jenkins VM on my local machine for playing arround with Jenkins, and later I want to introduce it in my company.

I set up a pipeline via Jenkinsfile in the repo like so:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'apmyp1990/lamp'
            args '-u root'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'service mysql start'
                sh 'mysql -u root -proot -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS text_db; CREATE DATABASE test_db;"'
                sh 'mysql -u root -proot -e "show databases;"'
                sh 'mysql -u root -proot -e "use test_db; source database/2018-06-26.sql;"'
                sh 'composer update'
                sh 'nightwatch'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I ran this pipeline it was not able to start docker, but I just added the user `tomcat` (jenkins is running with this user) to the docker group. During the first run everything is fine (despite nightwatch not starting - but that is not the problem). When I try to run this pipeline a second time, I get the following error:

```
Started by user admin
Obtained jenkinsfile from git https://bitbucket.org/{PROJECTNAME}.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/{Project}
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/{PROJECTNAME}.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/{PROJECTNAME}.git
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Arturs Bitbucket Account
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/{PROJECTNAME}.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision a9acc7b417f410ad4b3b8b73aeb905e7ace7df2b (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git checkout -f a9acc7b417f410ad4b3b8b73aeb905e7ace7df2b
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/opt/bitnami/git/bin/git checkout -f a9acc7b417f410ad4b3b8b73aeb905e7ace7df2b" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to unlink old 'web/typo3conf/ext/dce/Classes/Components/BackendView/SimpleBackendView.php': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'web/typo3conf/ext/dce/Classes/Components/DceContainer/Container.php': Permission denied
{much more of permission denied errors}

Previous HEAD position was 606c9db lamp:latest
HEAD is now at a9acc7b add root user

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$800(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2301)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout a9acc7b417f410ad4b3b8b73aeb905e7ace7df2b
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2325)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I then checked the permissions via bash (see linked pictures, because I am not able to copy from debian bash):
[root directory of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW6hC.png)

[web directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QupzO.png)

What am I missing to get the pipeline runnning properly? I do not understand why Jenkins has a problem with the permissions - jenkins is running with user tomcat, so everything should be fine?

Edit:

I have posted the wrong jenkinsfile, it should have the `args '-u root'` command in the agent section (see above). 
I now figured out that running the pipeline with this command causes the error. But when I am not using this command, I am not able to start the mysql server because of missing permissions. 
Starting the pipeline the first time (newly created pipeline) without `args '-u root'`, fails for starting the mysql server, but running the pipeline the next times with the args command will not produce any errors. Some suggestions anybody?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the workspace of the job empty and are you able to restart jenkins? I know it's a bit drastic but I had this once when a process was still running in the job (when I aborted it)

Comment: @lvthillo I am able to restart Jenkins, but the workspace of the job is not empty. If I create a new job, the first time it passes, but the second one and every following one will fail with permission denied.

I figured out that maybe the configuration of my docker image is faulty, but I cannot say what is responsible for the problem.